# Who creates the recipes for the food in the replicators?

Tags: star-trek

Every Federation ship has a pattern for, say, chocolate cake, and every slice is identical, down to the molecule. So theoretically, they want to make it as tasty as possible.

Has there ever been any details of how those recipes are created? Does the Federation simply have a staff of chefs who crafts them?

I whimsically imagined a competition on par with The British Bake-Off, possibly broadcast on the 23rd century analogue of the Food Network, with the prize being the honor of being THE chocolate cake, or whatever recipe. there's no cash prize, but I imagine the honor alone would be quite a feather in the cap.

Comment: I remember a few scenes where they appreciate "real" food and drink as being better than that generated by the replicators.  Maybe that's where they save the money to buy the dilithium crystals.

Comment: I'm sure that, since the same serving of food can be reproduced infinitely, some people who in our time might be hobbyist cooks would instead collect and trade replicator patterns.  "Default chocolate cake?  Not for me.  I've got this little chocolate cake pattern that's to die for".

Comment: “So theoretically, they want to make it as tasty as possible.”- The scene where Deanna Troi tries to get the replicator to make her a “real” chocolate sundae would imply the opposite: that the replicators make nutritious food first, and taste is secondary. It sounds kind of like modern meal replacements or ready to eat rations.

Comment: I imagine that if you don't specify a certain recipe, the replicator just selects the most popular one. If a certain other recipe then gains favour, that will be the one that is produced. It may also record personal stated preferences; "Next time, less sugar and more dark chocolate"; and adjust accordingly until the user is satisfied.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I think there was another answer about how Picard orders his tea that implies the replicator needs a guideline, i.e. when you ask it for tea it needs to know temperature and variety.

Comment: I think most of the arguments about a "real" sundae or the like isn't as much that the replicated one is not good, but that it's The Same. It's the difference between getting The Same burger at McDonald's, as opposed to getting a burger at some local restaurant. 

I'm sure it's an analogue to those who maintain that vinyl is "better" sound than CDs.